# Use ModalPopupExtender without having to set TargetControlID?

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, modalpopupextender

I'd like to use a modalpopupextender in my asp.net page to show a sub form. But it only has to show on specific conditions. Those conditions are determined in a piece of javascript code.

So, most importantly, the modal popup doesn't have to show on a button click. However, if I leave the property TargetControlID empty I get the following exception:

> The TargetControlID of 'ModalPopupExtender1' is not valid. The value cannot be null or empty. 
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>   System.InvalidOperationException: The
>   TargetControlID of
>   'ModalPopupExtender1' is
>   not valid. The value cannot be null or
>   empty.

Do I just have the TargetControlID to an hidden button or is there aslo a more decent option?

Comment: You used the HiddenField or the Button control as the target control Id. Did you face any difficulties having hiddenfield as targetcontrolId because i am now

Comment: @Deeptechtons, don't use a HiddenField. Use a Button control, but hide it with css (style="display: none;") as Mike mentioned in his answer.

Comment: you are perfectly right. The button solved my problem wonder what's wrong in using hidden fields

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Setting the TargetControlID to a hidden button(display:none;) is the best way as far as I know.

Comment: First I tried adding `<asp:Button Visible="false" />`, but that didn't work.  `<asp:Button style="display:none" />` is the key, as this answer indicates.

Comment: Don't know why but this worked for me too. I had a hidden <div id="hiddenID" style="display:none" /> but this didn't work. Only when changing to Button...

Answer (score 14):

The TargetControlID could also be set to a HiddenField type. That way you don't even need a button

Answer (score 0):

Crete a button and set it as your TargetControlId and give `style = "display:none"`

```xml
<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server" PopupControlID="Panel1" TargetControlID="btnPopup" 
        CancelControlID="btnClose" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" OkControlID="btnClose"></asp:ModalPopupExtender>

<asp:Button ID="btnPopup" runat="server" Text="PopUp" style = "display:none" />
```